# I can't figure out the nodes to have light trough the windows

Tags: rendering, light

Light won't come in, and any changes to the material won't work .. my question is . Why in the preview is looking near what i actually want and when I render is looking crappy.

[image]

I want it to look like the preview and this is the render.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make the lights shine through the windows, make sure you have your material's Shadow Mode set away from *Opaque*. Alpha hashed seems to work well for most situations.

[image: ShadowMode]

The reason the Material Preview looks better is because it uses a HDRI Environment image to provide lighting and reflections. To add your own (so it appears in the render), go to the shading tab and switch the drop box from **Object** to **World**. Add an *Environment Texture* and choose your image. The default ones that come with blender (.exr files) are in the blender folder at 2.90/datafiles/studiolights/world. If you want more, there are several places you can get them online for free. The most popular is HDRI Haven (https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/).

[image: HDRI]

Comment: oh !! thank you so much ! i wil come back to you if I need more info hihhi ty !!